# Issue with my Ruby Assignment

Tags: ruby

I am new to learn Ruby, I got an assignment from my teacher which I am trying to understand.
Here is the question. Consider the following code:

```
ary = Array.new(7, "--day")
ary[2] = "Tuesday"
ary[4] = "Thursday"
ary[7] = "Sunday"
ary[-1] = "Saturday"
puts ary[7]
puts ary[-4]
puts ary[-6, 2]
puts ary[2] = ary[7][-3,3]
puts ary.length
```

- Why does this code produce 6 lines of output? Where did the extra line come from?
- What is the value of ary[2] at the end?
- Why is the length (or size) of the array different than when we constructed it?

Comment: Try putting a `p ary` after every line, it should clarify a bit...

Comment: This is homework so I don't want to say that much. @BradWerth's advice is good; reading the [`Array.new`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-c-new), [`Array#[]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D), and [`Array#[]=`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D) docs would also be good.

Comment: I am learning Ruby, If You guys could help me . It will be a great help for me.Thanks

Comment: @AnnaWatson open your ruby console write each of these lines and check their output. You'll get to know what exactly each of these lines do

Answer (score 1):

I won't answer these questions directly, since it sounds like it's a homework assignment, but I will try to point you in the right direction.

1. Take a look at the documentation for Ruby's [Array#[]](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D). More specifically, take a look at which usages in your example code match the usages in the examples, and you might get a better idea of what's happening. Keep in mind that with Ruby, you can index from the *end* of your array by using negative index numbers.
2. Open up `irb` in the terminal and run the first 5 lines (all the `ary[]=` lines). Then run each of the `puts` lines individually and see what the output is. Keep in mind that lines with `=> something` are the *return* values, not what is being printed.
3. Take a look at [String#[]](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html#method-i-5B-5D), and try out the different parts of line 9 individually. For example, see what `ary[7]` does. Then see what `ary[7][-3, 3]` does. See what happens if you do `"Any Random String"[a_number, another_number]`.
4. After you first create the array, check `ary.length`. Then run each of the following lines, checking `ary.length` after each subsequent assignment.

Don't get discouraged, and don't listen to people telling you to give up. This stuff can be confusing when you first start out, but getting familiar with where to find documentation, how to use the command line tools, and how to experiment will make it much easier to explore and discover what your code is doing, when, and why.

If you ever need to try and figure out what is going on in your code, just open up `irb` in your terminal and start playing around with it, and you should be able to answer most of your questions through experimentation.